# Como visualizar Registros de una Consulta SQL con JOINTs no relacionados en una Vista con yii Framework 1.1

Tags: php, mysql, yii

estoy comenzando en el mundo yii framework en la version 1.1 y me es imposible visualizar los registros traidos desde una consulta pura. hace dias que no puedo solucionarlo , seguramente sea algo sencillo pero con mi pobre conocimiento no lo e podido solucionar aun.
Les muestro mi codigo a ver si me pueden ayudar.

mi modelo es :

```
public function traerRecibos()
{
return Yii::app()->db->createCommand(‘select idrecibo from tbl_recibo’)->queryAll();
}
```

mi Controller es :

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    $model = new TblRecibo('traerRecibos');
    $model->unsetAttributes();  // clear any default values
    if (isset($_GET['TblRecibo']))
        $model->attributes = $_GET['TblRecibo'];
    $this->render('index', array(
        'model' => $model,
    ));
}
```

Mi vista es:

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
'id'=>'tbl-recibo-grid', 'dataProvider'=>$model->traerRecibos(), 
 'columns'=>array( 
'idRecibo',
), )); ?>
```

al ejecutar este codigo sencillo el error es el siguiente:

```
( ! ) Fatal error: Call to a member function getData() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\yii1115\framework\zii\widgets\CBaseListView.php on line 111
```

y se observa esta imagen con el error completo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No puedo encontrar la solucion espero alguien me pueda ayudar.

Gracias y Saludos!

Comment: Hola, el error indica que estas intentando ejecutar la función `getData` a una variable que esta en NULL o no es un objeto. El error se da en la linea 11 del archivo `CBaseListView`. Nos podrías indicar que hay en esa linea para poder ayudarte un poco mejor?

Comment: Hola Andres gracias por tu rapida respuesta. Eso ya lo observe y en la linea 111  de la clase CBaseListVIew  hay esta linea de codigo: $this->dataProvider->getData();

Comment: inserte una imagen con el error que me genera para ver si aporta algo mas. Espero me puedan ayudar. Gracias!